# Loading inside a textarea after typing

Tags: javascript, textarea

```
<textarea id='txedit'></textarea>
<button id='btnload'>LOAD</button>

$('#btnload').on('click', function(){
    $('#txedit').load('test.php');
});
```

Before typing anything inside `txedit` the above code works i.e. `test.php` is loaded inside `txedit`.

After typing even a letter inside `txedit` - clicking on `btnload` doesn't load `test.php`.

Comment: Do you want to load `test.php` again when someone types in the textarea?

Comment: @window.document, of course, I want to replace all the typed content by `test.php`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of a unique property of the `<textarea>` element. When you put content in-between the tags, like so:

```html
<textarea> I'm in the middle! </textarea>
```

... that text serves as the "default" placeholder text, and once the user starts typing, it is no longer used, **even if you change it dynamically**. When you call `$('#txedit').load()`, JQuery is not putting the value of that AJAX call into the textarea as a text value, it is putting it in between the tags as default text!

What you want to do instead is pass the result of JQuery load to the *value* of the textarea, like so:

```html
<textarea id='txedit'></textarea>
<button id='btnload'>LOAD</button>
<script>
$('#btnload').on('click', function(){
    $.get('test.php', function(res){
        $('#txedit').val(res);
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: can't understand fully the story about `default placeholder` but - it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @qadenza [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7x3og5qm/2/). Type something in the text area and press the button. Notice nothing will happen. But if you inspect the text area. You will see the text. The text inside is the placeholder. When more text is added, jquery _is putting it in between the tags as default text_ which is no longer used.

Comment: @weegee, I see, thanks. Maybe the right question is for developers - what is the reason for such a behaviour?